# How to use SMS Retriever in Facebook Account Kit SDK to auto-fill SMS in android?

Tags: android, account-kit, sms-retriever-api

I'm using Facebook Account Kit in my application to check the phone number verification it will be working fine, but when I receive the SMS from Account Kit I can't able to auto-fill. I know google changed the SMS retriever policy for the following link (https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) but how can we implement SMS Retriever with facebook account kit anyone have idea about this.

In facebook account kit send request added the following code

```
 configurationBuilder.setReadPhoneStateEnabled(true);
 configurationBuilder.setReceiveSMS(true);
```

In Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Any one having idea to resolve?

Thanks!